# Обработка значений null в HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, null, htmlagilitypack

Делаю проверку на Null

```
var articule = "";
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tr2[i].SelectSingleNode("td[@class='resultInline resultPartCode   ']").InnerText.Trim()))
        {
              articule =
              tr2[i].SelectSingleNode("td[@class='resultInline resultPartCode   ']").InnerText.Trim();
        }
```

Также пробовал

`tr2[i].SelectSingleNode("td[@class='resultInline resultPartCode   ']").InnerText!=null`

Все равно выдает ошибку 
**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если SelectSingleNode может вернуть null, то проверять надо перед обращением к свойству InnerText.

```
var t = tr2[i].SelectSingleNode("td[@class='resultInline resultPartCode']");
var articule = (t != null) ? t.InnerText.Trim() : "";
```